# SQL Server not returning correct output from a user defined function

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to call a UDF from another UDF and hoping to get desired output. However, SQL Server is not returning anything in the second UDF.

My calls are:

```
DECLARE @V_F VARCHAR(200)
EXEC @V_F = dbo.fnCalcDiscount 220,'1234567812345679','Thailand'
PRINT @V_F
GO

DECLARE @V_F VARCHAR(200)
EXEC @V_F = dbo.groupsanddiscounts '1234567812345679','Thailand',220,220
PRINT @V_F
GO
```

Output:

```
110
0
```

Body of `groupsanddiscounts`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[groupsanddiscounts]
    (@p_PROMOCODE VARCHAR(50),
     @p_COUNTRY VARCHAR(100),
     @p_TOTVAL INT,
     @p_NEWSIMCOST INT) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(300) 
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @p_FINALVALUE VARCHAR(300)

    SELECT @p_FINALVALUE =  dbo.fnCalcDiscount (@p_NEWSIMCOST, @p_PROMOCODE, @p_COUNTRY)
    RETURN @p_FINALVALUE         
END
```

Body of `fnCalcDiscount`

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCalcDiscount] 
    (@p_TOTVAL INT, 
     @p_PROMOCODE VARCHAR(200), 
     @p_COUNTRY VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS VARCHAR(300)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @retResult VARCHAR(300) 

    SELECT @retResult = '110'
    RETURN @retResult
END
```

Any idea what is going berserk?

Thanks

[image: Output]

Comment: still the same output . updating my question with the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `select`:

```
select dbo.fnCalcDiscount(220, '1234567812345679', 'Thailand')
```

I'm surprised that `exec` doesn't simply return an error.  It is usually used for stored procedures and SQL code.

Comment: even better `select @V_F = dbo.fnCalcDiscount(220, '1234567812345679', 'Thailand')`